# Stuck partial differential question $f(x)= 4x^3+3x^2y+xy+3y$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I stumbled upon a question which I cannot recognise, how I should attempt it?

Given that
$f(x)= 4x^3+3x^2y+xy+3y$

Obtain expression for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$,$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$,$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}$

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "what kind of question is it".. do you not recognise the notation or something?

Comment: Yea my bad >.<, I haven't seen the notation and I can't find it anywhere in my notes.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please share your thoughts on your problem in future. It will help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is the partial derivative with respect to $x$; that is, it is just like a derivative with respect to $x$ but where the other variables - $y$ in this case - are taken as constants. Also $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$ is the derivative with respect to $x$ followed by the derivative with respect to $y$ (or *vice versa*).

For example, let $f$ be defined by $f(x, y)=4x^3+3x^2y+xy+3y$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}&= 12x^2 +6xy+y, \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}&=3x^2+x+3, \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}&=6x+1.
\end{align}$$

Comment: just wondering my friend for differential of y I got 3x^2 + x + 3, as differential of 3y leaves 3 ?

Comment: @Chippi You're right, my mistake. I've corrected it now.

Comment: @Chippi Don't forget to upvote. Also, consider using `$3x^2+x+3$` for $3x^2+x+3$ instead of 3x^2+x+3.

Comment: I'd love to and tried, however, i got this message "vote cast by those with 15 or less reputation are recorded..." I am not sure on how to fix this. But I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Chippi Ah, you need reputation points first. You get these by asking and answering questions to a given standard. You might get some upvotes and less downvotes for this question by formatting with MathJax and giving some background to the problem.

Comment: Thank you once again, I'll reformat this page to look more presentable.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question about partial derivatives. When you calculate them, think about taking the normal derivative with respect to the variable while holding all other variables constant.

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ This mean we will take the derivative with respect to $x$ while hold $y$ constant.

So the first question is to calculate

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 12x^2+6xy + y + 0$

Comment: You should mark this as answer so this question wont be up anymore.

Comment: @Chippi Even though you marked this answer it does not talk anything about the third problem you have. I really doubt that you know the meaning of the third problem.

Comment: @A---B This is my first post, so please forgive me if I am sloppy :<

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the concept of partial derivatives? $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ stands for the derivative as only the variable $x$ changes, that is the other variables ($y$ in the case of two variables function as you had) are taken as constants.

For example, for $f=4x^3+3x^2y+xy+3y$ we would have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= 12x^2 +6xy+y$